# Mutate over multiple columns, skip NA values

Tags: r, dplyr

**Reprex**

```
data <- data.frame(
  subjid = c(3,4,7,8,11,14,18,19,20,21),
  pct_pvr_3 = c(10,NA,NA,NA,20,NA,70,NA,NA,NA),
  pct_pvr_2 = c(90,NA,90,30,30,50,30,100,NA,NA),
  pct_pvr_1 = c(NA,NA,10,20,30,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  pct_pvr_0 = c(NA,NA,NA,50,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
)
```

**Problem**: I want to create a new column `hscore` with the following formula:

`hscore = ((0*pct_pvr_0)+(1*pct_pvr_1)+(2*pct_pvr_2)+(3*pct_pvr_3))`

However, as many of the columns are `NA`, the resulting column is full of `NA`s. I think I may be able to get around this issue with a bunch of `if_else` statements. Before going that route, I wanted to see if there were any simpler solutions using `dplyr` or other packages.

**Current Code**:

```
data <- data %>%
     mutate(hscore = ((0*pct_pvr_0)+(1*pct_pvr_1)+(2*pct_pvr_2)+(3*pct_pvr_3)))
```

**Current Output**:

```
# A tibble: 56 x 6
   subjid pct_pvr_0 pct_pvr_1 pct_pvr_2 pct_pvr_3 hscore
    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1      3        NA        NA        90        10     NA
 2      4        NA        NA        NA        NA     NA
 3      7        NA        10        90        NA     NA
 4      8        50        20        30        NA     NA
 5     11        NA        30        50        20     NA
 6     14        NA        NA       100        NA     NA
 7     18        NA        NA        30        70     NA
 8     19        NA        NA        NA        NA     NA
 9     20        NA        NA        NA        NA     NA
10     21        NA        NA        NA        NA     NA
```

**`dplyr` Solution**: Replaced `NA`s as `0`

```
data <- data %>% 
replace(is.na(.),0) %>% 
mutate(hscore = ((0*pct_pvr_0)+(1*pct_pvr_1)+(2*pct_pvr_2)+(3*pct_pvr_3)))

data
   subjid pct_pvr_3 pct_pvr_2 pct_pvr_1 pct_pvr_0 hscore
1       3        10        90         0         0    210
2       4         0         0         0         0      0
3       7         0        90        10         0    190
4       8         0        30        20        50     80
5      11        20        30        30         0    150
6      14         0        50         0         0    100
7      18        70        30         0         0    270
8      19         0       100         0         0    200
9      20         0         0         0         0      0
10     21         0         0         0         0      0
```

Comment: What do you want the result to be when there are `NA` values? Do you want to treat the `NA`s as 0s, or 1s, or the mean of the non-missing values, or something else?

Comment: I want to omit the value if there is an `NA` value. For example, for `subjid ==3`, the h-score would be equal to 210 [(90*2)+(10*3)]. Since there are no values for the `pct_pvr_1` or `pct_pvr_0`, they are ignored in the calculation. Hope that provides additional clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a straight forward `{tidyverse}` solution. `rowwise()` is a real lifesaver!

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  subjid = c(3,4,7,8,11,14,18,19,20,21),
  pct_pvr_3 = c(10,NA,NA,NA,20,NA,70,NA,NA,NA),
  pct_pvr_2 = c(90,NA,90,30,30,50,30,100,NA,NA),
  pct_pvr_1 = c(NA,NA,10,20,30,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  pct_pvr_0 = c(NA,NA,NA,50,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(hscore = sum((1*pct_pvr_1),(2*pct_pvr_2),(3*pct_pvr_3), na.rm=T))

   subjid pct_pvr_3 pct_pvr_2 pct_pvr_1 pct_pvr_0 hscore
    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1      3        10        90        NA        NA    210
 2      4        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
 3      7        NA        90        10        NA    190
 4      8        NA        30        20        50     80
 5     11        20        30        30        NA    150
 6     14        NA        50        NA        NA    100
 7     18        70        30        NA        NA    270
 8     19        NA       100        NA        NA    200
 9     20        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
10     21        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
```

EDIT:

If you want to keep `NA`s where all columns are `NA`, then you can use [Paul Poncet's](https://github.com/paulponcet) `sumNA()` from `{bazar}`.

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(hscore = bazar::sumNA((1*pct_pvr_1),(2*pct_pvr_2),(3*pct_pvr_3), na.rm=T)) -> df
```

It's actually pretty neat. This is the function:

```
function (..., na.rm = FALSE) 
{
    x <- unlist(list(...))
    if (na.rm && length(x) && all(is.na(x))) 
        return(x[1] + NA)
    sum(x, na.rm = na.rm)
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `rowwise` to take advantage of sum's `na.rm` arg!

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks. :)

Comment: I don't use `rowwise` very frequently, but I will keep this in mind in the future. Marked this as the answer, as it provides a solution to the original question. However, in this case I can replace the `NA`s with `0`s due to the nature of the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  left_join(data %>%
    pivot_longer(-subjid) %>%
    group_by(subjid) %>%
    summarise(hscore = sum(coalesce(value * parse_number(name), 0)))
  )
```

parse_number() extracts the ending number part of the column name.
coalesce takes care of the NA's by replacing any NA with zero.

```
Joining, by = "subjid"
   subjid pct_pvr_3 pct_pvr_2 pct_pvr_1 pct_pvr_0 hscore
1       3        10        90        NA        NA    210
2       4        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
3       7        NA        90        10        NA    190
4       8        NA        30        20        50     80
5      11        20        30        30        NA    150
6      14        NA        50        NA        NA    100
7      18        70        30        NA        NA    270
8      19        NA       100        NA        NA    200
9      20        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
10     21        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd (temporarily) replace the `NA` values with `0` and frame the problem as matrix multiplication:

```
data$hscore = rowSums(as.matrix(replace(data[-1], is.na(data[-1]), 0)) %*% diag(3:0))
data
#    subjid pct_pvr_3 pct_pvr_2 pct_pvr_1 pct_pvr_0 hscore
# 1       3        10        90        NA        NA    210
# 2       4        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
# 3       7        NA        90        10        NA    190
# 4       8        NA        30        20        50     80
# 5      11        20        30        30        NA    150
# 6      14        NA        50        NA        NA    100
# 7      18        70        30        NA        NA    270
# 8      19        NA       100        NA        NA    200
# 9      20        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
# 10     21        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
```

Comment: I actually think it would be acceptable to simply replace all of the `NA`s with `0`. Thanks for the idea! (it's been a long week so I'm a bit brain dead at this point...)

I prefer `dplyr`, so I will add the exact solution I used as an edit.

Answer (score 4):

how about that?

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, 0))
  ) %>%
  mutate(hscore = ((0*pct_pvr_0)+(1*pct_pvr_1)+(2*pct_pvr_2)+(3*pct_pvr_3))) %>%
  select(subjid, hscore) %>%
  right_join(data)
```

yields:

```
   subjid hscore pct_pvr_3 pct_pvr_2 pct_pvr_1 pct_pvr_0
1       3    210        10        90        NA        NA
2       4      0        NA        NA        NA        NA
3       7    190        NA        90        10        NA
4       8     80        NA        30        20        50
5      11    150        20        30        30        NA
6      14    100        NA        50        NA        NA
7      18    270        70        30        NA        NA
8      19    200        NA       100        NA        NA
9      20      0        NA        NA        NA        NA
10     21      0        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also do with `across` (similar to @JonSpring's solution involving `coalesce` and `parse_number`), but without reshaping to 'long' format.  i.e. loop `across` the columns that starts with 'pct', get the column name with `cur_column`, then extract the numeric part with `parse_number` from `readr`, convert the NA to 0 with either `coalesce` or `replace_na` and `reduce` the columns to a single column by adding (`+`) the corresponding elements of each column, finally bind the single column output from `transmute` with original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
  transmute(across(starts_with('pct'), 
       ~ coalesce(. * readr::parse_number(cur_column()), 0))) %>% 
  transmute(hscore = reduce(cur_data(), `+`)) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
#   subjid pct_pvr_3 pct_pvr_2 pct_pvr_1 pct_pvr_0 hscore
#    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1      3        10        90        NA        NA    210
# 2      4        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
# 3      7        NA        90        10        NA    190
# 4      8        NA        30        20        50     80
# 5     11        20        30        30        NA    150
# 6     14        NA        50        NA        NA    100
# 7     18        70        30        NA        NA    270
# 8     19        NA       100        NA        NA    200
# 9     20        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
#10     21        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(data)[
  ,
  hscore := rowSums(
    mapply(
      "*",
      .SD,
      as.numeric(gsub(".*_", "", names(.SD)))
    ),
    na.rm = TRUE
  ),
  .SDcols = patterns("pct_pvr_")
][]
```

gives

```
    subjid pct_pvr_3 pct_pvr_2 pct_pvr_1 pct_pvr_0 hscore
 1:      3        10        90        NA        NA    210
 2:      4        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
 3:      7        NA        90        10        NA    190
 4:      8        NA        30        20        50     80
 5:     11        20        30        30        NA    150
 6:     14        NA        50        NA        NA    100
 7:     18        70        30        NA        NA    270
 8:     19        NA       100        NA        NA    200
 9:     20        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
10:     21        NA        NA        NA        NA      0
```